# PHP - First time login page

Tags: php

I am trying to setup a website that will know if a user has logged into the website before. The MYSQL table has a username, password and firstLogin field. The firstLogin field is an integer field containing 1 if the user has not logged and 2 if they have logged in in the past.

The login sysetm logs in and starts a session as it should do therefore i am certain the count is returning the value of 1. The problem that i am having is the website is going straight to homepage.php even if the firstLogin integer is set to 1. The website should be going to welcome.php whilst performing an update operation to change the integer to 2. Ive been staring at this for about a week now. Hope you can help.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST ['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT username, password,firstLogin FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='".$myusername."' and password= sha1('".$mypassword."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     print_r($row); 
     exit;

    if ($row ['firstLogin']=="1")
        {
        $sql2 ="UPDATE $tbl_name SET firstLogin = '2' WHERE username ='".$myusername."'";  
        session_start();

        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword");
        header("welcome.php");
        }
        else

        {
        session_start();        
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword");
        header("location:home.php");
        }
        }else
     {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI, your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: @Daniel only if `$myusername` is not escaped.

Comment: true but i like to give this warning anyways.

Comment: You're just doing it all wrong.  You're susceptible to both SQL injection attacks and session hijacking.

Comment: $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword); Will this help? i didnt include this section of the script as i didnt find it applicable

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jeff Parker's fixes, I might suggest extracting your session starting code into a function so that you're not repeating your code.  I already see your code introducing a copy and paste error.

Also, I think `$row['firstLogin'] == 1` would be acceptable, considering that the row will be returning an integer as opposed to a string.

```
if ($row ['firstLogin']=="1")
    {
    $sql2 ="UPDATE $tbl_name SET firstLogin = '2' WHERE username ='".$myusername."'";  
    session_start();

    session_register("myusername"); //!! This is possibly an error, you're saving myusername as opposed to $myusername
    session_register("mypassword"); // Same as above
    header("welcome.php");  // This is possibly an error since the header is missing the "location:" part
    }
    else

    {
    session_start();        
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:home.php");
    }
```

Can be turned into

```
if ($row ['firstLogin']=="1")
    {
    $sql2 ="UPDATE $tbl_name SET firstLogin = '2' WHERE username ='".$myusername."'";  
    start_session_and_redirect('welcome.php');
    }
    else

    {
    start_session_and_redirect('home.php');
    }
```

then place a function ...

```
function start_session_and_redirect($location){
session_start();
session_register("myusername"); // I'm also wondering if that's supposed to be $myusername instead of "myusername...
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:$location");
}
```

You have an error in your above code possibly if php doesn't automatically fix it, where welcome.php doesn't have "location:" in front of it, which can be entirely prevented by having a function for the repeat functionality, something you should always be looking to eliminate from your code.

Comment: Well spotted on the "location: welcome.php", I completely missed that one.  +1!

Comment: Oh!
btw, you're never actually executing the update code, sooooo
I'm hugely suspecting that your `if ($row ['firstLogin']=="1")` is NEVER true, thus it's always redirecting to home.php, plus even if it was true, you still wouldn't end up changing the the value in the table.

Comment: I did spot this one, but the update changes firstLogin to 2 ... which should bring back the "home.php" page, which is what is apparently happening at the moment.  1 is the status we want, apparently ... an error it seems to be, but I don't think it's related to this specific problem.

Comment: @Jeff Parker are you sure? He says it never actually goes to welcome.php, which suggest that `$row['firstLogin'] == 1` is just never true, not that it's necessarily `== 2`.

also, since `$sql2` is never executed, it should still be 1 in the table anyway since he never calls `mysql_query($sql2)` or whatever the function is..

Comment: @Anther You've just rephrased what I said, I think.  We can agree that the firstLogin value is not 1, and that the query which isn't run should set it to 2 ... but we're trying to figure out if it should be 1.  The running of the query is dependent on the value being 1 in the first place, so it's not correct, but it's a step we're not getting to because the value's not 1 in the first place ... or so it seems at least.  I'm hoping the print_r can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($row ['firstLogin']="1") // wrong
```

You're doing an assignment.  It should be a comparison.

```
if ($row ['firstLogin'] == "1") // right
```

---

There's also an error in the query used to retrieve the user data.

```
// -- This is wrong, missing the ending parenthesis, and will not run.
$sql="SELECT username, password,firstLogin FROM $tbl_name WHERE
    username='".$myusername."' and password= sha1('".$mypassword."'";

// -- This includes the ending parenthesis, and should run.
$sql="SELECT username, password,firstLogin FROM $tbl_name WHERE 
    username='".$myusername."' and password= sha1('".$mypassword."')";
```

Comment: I don't see any other errors as part of that process in the code you've pasted.  Try print_r on the $row variable, and let us know what the result is?  (ie.  "print_r($row); exit;" after the mysql_fetch_array call).

Comment: that doesnt do anything, i shall edit the question to include the whole script.

Comment: Pointed out a second error in the new code.  Once it is corrected, with the print_r and exit, this should now output a user row.  If this is the case, tell us what it is, then remove the print_r and exit :)